# Has the Google Play Services library been updated?

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-location, android-geofence

I'm working on an app which uses Geofences. Today while looking through the documentation for them, I noticed a new transition type (Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL) as well as a couple new methods for Geofence.Builder

I'm not able to use these new methods or the new transition type with the Play Services library I have installed. I've checked the SDK manager for updates but didn't see anything. Does anybody know if there's a way to update my Play Services library, or has the documentation just been updated early?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was added as part of Google Play Services 4.0 as per the [announcement blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/google-play-services-40.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I ended up just deleting the Play services package through the SDK manager and then re-downloading (didn't have an option to update) and now am able to use the new features